# how to show pop up on cell render in ag grid angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an angular ag-grid. The data is populated by using web API. one of the columns in the ag-grid is "Specimen Id". Right now, I  click on the Specimen Id, and using cell rendered I am able to get the details of
a particular specimen Id. But I want to show the details in a modal popup. please tell me how to do this!!

Comment: Hi, do you want to get the relevant record of the details and use it outside the ag-grid?

Comment: on specimen Id click im calling api to get the details. How to show that in modal popup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved this way
[component-cell-renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/)

can you cellRenderer and show detail in popup

Comment: no, it is creating a separate column with the button. I just want to click on the specimen id to get it displayed on modal Pop Up